# on button click switch xml layout page

Tags: android, xml, eclipse, android-intent, android-manifest

I know that this question was already asked but I get an error when I do this:

`Intent toNextPage = new Intent(this, After_report_page.class);
startActivity(toNextPage);`

How can I fix this (I want that on button click that xml layout switches)?

Thank you,
Boaz

Comment: post your logcat and appropriate java code

Comment: what error do you get?

Comment: `this` refers to the `Context` object. I am pretty sure you are trying this inside the `onClick` function, where `this` refers to the listener object. You should replace it with `<CurrentActivityName>.this`.

Comment: please accept an answer if you solved your problem/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use Activity Context to start next Activity instead of View as:

```
Intent toNextPage = new Intent(Your_current_Activity.this,
                                             After_report_page.class); 
startActivity(toNextPage);
```

or you can use  `view.getContext()`  to get context from starting new Activity as:

```
Intent toNextPage = new Intent(view.getContext(), After_report_page.class); 
startActivity(toNextPage);
```

Comment: `Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method getContext() from the type View` is listed as error when i try the second option, when i try the firs it crashes

Comment: @BoazKatzir : `view` mean parameter in onClick method like `onClick(View view){Intent toNextPage = new Intent(view.getContext(), After_report_page.class); 
startActivity(toNextPage);}`

Comment: Okay now it works I just changed `view.getContext()` to `v.GetContext` because i use `public void onClick(View v)`

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
      Button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        Intent toNextPage = new Intent(YourActivity.this, After_report_page.class);
                        startActivity(toNextPage);
                    }
                });
```

if you put this as parameter for intent inside on click event it will not work.

Answer (score 1):

Try as below:

> ```
> private Context mContext;
>    public class IntentActionDemo extends Activity 
>   {
>      mContext=IntentActionDemo.this;
>
>      @Override
>      public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
>     setContentView(R.layout.main);        
>     Button butn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.intentButton);
>
>         butn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
>             public void onClick(View v) {
>       Intent myIntent = new Intent(mContext, After_report_page.class);
>       startActivity(myIntent);
>      }
>     });
> ```

Answer (score 0):

//I did this yesterday as simple by using radio button

make 2 layouts in one xml using radio check which one is clicked and make your layout visibility to gone and visible vise verse.

```
final RadioButton ccDoc=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.cc_doc);
        ccDoc.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if(ccDoc.isChecked()){
                    findViewById(R.id.cc_doc_lay).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    findViewById(R.id.outside_doc_lay).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }else {
                    findViewById(R.id.outside_doc_lay).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    findViewById(R.id.cc_doc_lay).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            }
        });
```