# How Can I Create Multiple Views (i.e., layout .xml files) using Xamarin.Android and Display Them Depending on What Navigation Button is Clicked?

Tags: c#, xml, xamarin.android

I am developing a Xamarin.Android app. I will have multiple tabs to select from. I want to implement functionality so that when I click on a navigation tab (from the Navigation Drawer to the left), a view specific to that tab will be displayed. I want to be able to call xml files from the **layout** folder when needed.

I tried using Fragments, but I encountered a message in Visual Studio 2019 saying that Fragments are obsolete. I also checked this question [on button click switch xml layout page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14723851/on-button-click-switch-xml-layout-page) but it doesn't make sense to me. I also tried using `SetContentView` from the main program and adding my xml file as a parameter, however it was causing a build error.

My `SetContentView` code was this: `SetContentView(Resources.Layout.rego)`with **rego** being the xml file, but, as I mentioned, is causing a build error.

This is one of the if statements for calling the xml file, however it does not work (causing a build error):

```
public bool OnNavigationItemSelected(IMenuItem item)
        {
            int id = item.ItemId;

            if (id == Resource.Id.nav_rego)
            {
                SetContentView(Resource.Layout.rego);
            }
```

**nav_rego** is the navigation tab in the Navigation Drawer.

I am expecting to have an app with navigation functionality so that once a tab is clicked on, a view specific to that tab is displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I was on the right path. I created menu items for the navigation bar and checked the id of the selected navigation button against the id of the navigation buttons. I added layouts under `Resources > layout` and checked if the selected id (navigation button) was a match for the id of the navigation link/button I specified. For example:

```
public bool OnNavigationItemSelected(IMenuItem item)
{
    int id = item.ItemId;

    if (id == Resource.Id.rego_page_nav)
    {
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.rego_page_layout);
        //code here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Fragment` class is deprecated in `Android.App` indeed(`using Android.App;`), but the Support Library Fragments are here to stay and are part of the new Android Jetpack components.
Because fragments play a big part in Android development. Just make sure to update your project by using Support Library Fragments, using the following namespace in your fragment class:

```
using Android.Support.V4.App;
```

instead of

```
 using Android.App;
```

For example:

```
public bool OnNavigationItemSelected(IMenuItem item)
    {
        int id = item.ItemId;

        if (id == Resource.Id.nav_rego)
        {
            var fragment = SpinnerFragment.NewInstance();

            //var fragmentManager = FragmentManager;
            var fragmentManager = SupportFragmentManager;
            var ft = fragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
            ft.Replace(Resource.Id.LLTarget, fragment);
            ft.Commit();

        }

   }
```

Note:

SpinnerFragment is a Fragment class extends Fragment

```
 public class SpinnerFragment : Fragment{

    public static Fragment NewInstance()
    {
        Fragment fragment = new SpinnerFragment();
        return fragment;
    }

   // other code
  }
```